# Nested query in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, orm

i'm try to remove duplicated row with distinct or annotate then measure count of something.(mysql:8 ,django:2.2)

sql

```
select t1.cp_id, count(*) from (
    SELECT user_id, product_id, cp_id, count(*) as cnt FROM A 
    where created_at between '2021-07-12' and '2021-07-13'
    group by user_id, product_id, cp_id
) as t1
group by t1.cp_id
```

my queryset

```
A.objects.filter(
    created_at__gte='2021-07-12',
    created_at__lt='2021-07-13'
).values('cp_id', 'user_id', 'product_id').annotate(cnt=Count('cp_id')).values('cp_id').annotate(count=Count('cp_id'))
```

this queryset sql

```
SELECT A.cp_id, COUNT(cp_id`) AS count FROM A 
WHERE (
created_at >= 2021-07-11 19:30:00 AND
 created_at < 2021-07-12 19:30:00 AND
)
GROUP BY cp_id, created_at
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

I'm confused why Django ignores the order of my commands and executes the last query commands on the original table (not the table where the duplicate data is deleted)

Thanks if you have a solution or idea to remove the rows that have the same 'cp_id', 'user_id', 'product_id' (not from the database), then calculate the number of repetitions per cp_id

my modele.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cp = models.ForeignKey(CP, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: just need to confirm one thing why are you using annotate with count twice for cp_id?

Comment: @OpticPython Because I want to make sure that in my calculations my products are counted only once for every ('cp_id', 'user_id', 'product_id', 'created_at')  and then I find out how many cp products are sold each day.There may be several rows in the table for every ('cp_id', 'user_id', 'product_id', 'created_at')

Comment: have you tired the below query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
A.objects.filter(
    created_at__range=[2021-07-12, 2021-07-14],
).annotate(cp_count=Count('cp_id')).values('cp_count', 'user_id', 'product_id', 'created_at').order_by('created_at')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you told me. But it still does not cover the second part of my query. After deleting duplicate row, I want to know the number of products per cp

Comment: it will be better if you can share models.py so i can help you.

Comment: i add my model to question :)